# Stop showing a certain file in git commits

Tags: git

In one of my repositories, I accidentally didn't add a certain security related file to my gitignore for a few commits, so if I were to push this up to github the old file with sensitive information would show up if you looked at old commits.

Is there a way to remove this file from previous commits so it can't be seen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the [filter-branch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) command. Github has a good [write-up](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) of how to use filter-branch to remove sensitive data.